# DVC Line Series Chart with Multiple Series

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

How do you add multiple series with a DVC Line Series graph?

I have the following code to produce my first series:

WPF:

```
<DVC:Chart Name="Chart"
           Background="#463F3F">                
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:LineSeries Title=" Monthly Count" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
        </DVC:LineSeries>
    </DVC:Chart.Series>
    <DVC:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Style>
    </DVC:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
</DVC:Chart>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadLineChartData();

    }

    private void LoadLineChartData()
    {
        ((LineSeries)Chart.Series[0]).ItemsSource =
            new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>[]{
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now, 100),
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), 130),
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2), 150),
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3), 125),
    new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4),155)};
    }
}
}
```

The C# code is where the series are set, i just need to know how to add another one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in code behind. Remove the `<DVC:Chart.Series>` section from your XAML.
Then you can set all your series programmatically (this example is based on your XAML and add one series, replicate as many time as you want (i.e. with a FOR loop) to add several series):

```
private void LoadLineChartData()
{
    //Chart is your chart object in Xaml
    //declare your series
    LineSeries ls = new LineSeries();

    ls.Title = "Monthly Count";
    ls.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("Key");
    ls.DependentValueBinding = new Binding("Value");

    ls.ItemsSource = new KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>[]
    {
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now, 100),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), 130),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2), 150),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3), 125),
        new KeyValuePair<DateTime,int>(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(4),155)};

        // then add it to the chart
        Chart.Series.Add(ls);    
    }
}
```